# Use of two or more than two Adverbs in one sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use two adverbs with the same meaning in a sentence? For example:

> I **also** do drawing **as well**.

Comment: There were some major formatting problems in your question.  You had put a large photo of a man (yourself) and you had left the "true/false" section (probably cut and paste".  I've tried to fix these.  Please take a look at the [help] to see how the site works.

Comment: I hope you've now read the [help] pages.  What you can do to make the question better is explain **why** you think it is wrong.  You can [edit].  ***Don't comment***

Comment: For example, you might say "I heard someone say this, but in my language it would be bad to use both "also" and "as well" in the same sentence" Or you might say "I used this in my report, but my teacher marked it incorrect."

Answer (score 0):

It is not incorrect grammar, but it is redundant. In good English, you would avoid using both "also" and "as well" in the same sentence.

Sentences like this are quite common in spoken English, but should be avoided in written English. In spoken English you can't go back to edit, but you usually can edit your written English.